# What can I do to make this ghci infereced signature to compile

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-inference, ghci

I have a `RWST` Monad, and have some *generic* functions to interact with the `Writer` part of it.

For reference, `RWST` is like this:

```
newtype RWST r w s m a = RWST {runRWST :: r -> s -> m (a, s, w)}
instance (Monoid w, Monad m) => Monad (RWST r w s m)
instance Functor m => Functor (RWST r w s m)
instance (Monoid w, MonadFix m) => MonadFix (RWST r w s m)
instance (Monoid w, MonadPlus m) => MonadPlus (RWST r w s m)
instance Monoid w => MonadTrans (RWST r w s)
instance (Monoid w, MonadIO m) => MonadIO (RWST r w s m)
instance (Monoid w, Monad m) => MonadWriter w (RWST r w s m)
instance (Monad m, Monoid w) => MonadState s (RWST r w s m)
instance (Monad m, Monoid w) => MonadReader r (RWST r w s m)
instance (Monoid w, Monad m) => MonadRWS r w s (RWST r w s m)
```

So I had a data `Definition` that is like this:

```
type Definition = RWS SapphireReader DefWriter DefState
```

Where the `DefWriter` is just `type DefWriter = Seq Error` *(Error is defined by me, not the `Control.Monad.Error` one)*.

I had a working function:

```
tellPError :: Position -> ParseError -> Definition ()
tellPError posn err = tell (singleton $ PError posn err)
```

Now I need a new RWST and wish to have a *generic* `tellPError`, I tried removing the signature, loading the file in **ghci** and doing `:t tellPError`.

```
λ :t tellPError
tellPError :: MonadWriter (Seq Error.Error) m => Position -> ParseError -> m ()
```

I try giving my function that signature in the code, it won't compile:

```
Non type-variable argument
      in the constraint: MonadWriter (Seq Error) m
    (Use -XFlexibleContexts to permit this)
    In the type signature for `tellPError':
      tellPError :: MonadWriter (Seq Error) m =>
                    Position -> ParseError -> m ()
```

Do I really need this flag? I tried it and it did compile but wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, according to Haskell's 2010 report sections [4.1.2](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-650004.1.2) and [4.1.3](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-660004.1.3), class constraints must be of the form:

```
class   →   qtycls tyvar
        |   qtycls ( tyvar atype1 … atypen )        (n ≥ 1)
```

Where `qtycls` is a class name, `tyvar` is a type variable and the `atype` is, basically, almost any type. Note however that both rules are of the form `qtycls (? tyvar ...`.

However that signature contains the constraint:

```
MonadWriter (Seq Error.Error) m
```

Which is of the form:

```
qtycls (gtycon1 gtycon2) tyvar
```

Hence the error: the `gtycon1`s should be type variable, not a type-constructor.
In order to express that contraint you must use the `-XFlexibleContexts` extension.

An alternative is to get rid of the constraint is by specifying which monad `m` you want, reducing polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've been looking at this problem now and came up with the idea of specifying that is a `RWS` to the right of the `=>`, that seemed to do the trick:

```
tellPError :: Position -> ParseError -> RWS r (Seq Error) s ()
tellPError posn err = tell (singleton $ PError posn err)
```

Compiles and works how it should!